# Returning from the top of the code in Java,How?

Tags: java, swing, loops, joptionpane

is there any other way to return from the top of the code?
I already tried using Scanner and it worked but now I want to use YES_NO_OPTION in JOption but i dont have any idea to return from the top of the code using this method.

This is the last part of the program:

```
int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Continue?","Choose",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
//What should i put here inside the bracket?
}
if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for using");
}
```

and What should i put in the top of the code to read my Command inside the Bracket?
any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want a loop:

```
int selectedOption = JOptionPane.YES_OPTION; // by default
while (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // do your stuff
    selectedOption = 
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Continue?","Choose",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
}
```

Comment: yeah I want a loop, but i dont know what to put in the top of the code to read the whole process again.

do you have any advise?

Comment: My advice is in my answer. The code that you want to repeat is `// do your stuff`.

Comment: please whats real reason for loop, why not simpler if - else if - else, because I think by default JOptionPane isn't reusable, missing there CLOSED and CANCELL (internal closing events), else is for  empty value represented closed and cancell

Comment: The OP wants to repeat the same thing again and again until he chooses to stop thanks to a JOptionPane, hence the loop. I don't understand your objection about reusability. No JOptionPane is reused here.